# Eclipse with STS, new Spring boot project "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: spring, maven

I just installed eclipse luna and the Spring STS feature. I then created a new "Spring Starter Project" via the provided wizard but it's created with a pom error:

Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from/to spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

How do I fix this? I went looking for Spring forums to post this question but it appears they've been shut down in lieu of posting here.

Craig

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to a expired or self-signed (unlikely in this case) certificate. 
You could attempt to install the certificate in your JVM trust store as described (here)[https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/SSLHandshakeException+-+unable+to+find+valid+certification+path+to+requested+target]

But it's not a good idea to trust expired or self-signed certificates from third parties. I would look to install an older version of the module by modifying the POM probably.